# Add Python Application to accept incoming network connections

Tags: python, django, macos

While running Django webserver, I get a popup window that says -
[image: Do you want the application "python" to accept incoming network connections?]
I always click "Allow" and I can see in my Security & Privacy settings that "python" is there and is set to "Allow incoming connections," but I still get this popup. How can I prevent this popup from reappearing?

Thanks.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527700/do-you-want-the-application-to-accept-incoming-network-connection

Comment: This is not offtopic, it's helped me several times while programming Python code that uses network connections. Please take your pedantic urges and rearrange some grocery store shelves, or something. Someone had to go ask a second question about the accepted answer because of this.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can resolve this by signing the offending application binary yourself.

```
Disclaimer: Signing an application yourself will make an application appear more
secure to the operating system, when in reality it isn’t. Only sign applications
that you are 100% sure are not spyware or otherwise malicious. If you have any
doubts, just uninstall/reinstall.
```

**Part 1: Create a Signing Identity**

The solution I’m going for – signing the app myself – requires that I create a Signing Identity, also known as Signing Certificate. This is very easy to do:

1. Open Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access.
2. From the Keychain Access menu, choose Certificate Assistant > Create a Certificate.
3. Fill in a name for the certificate. This name appears in the Keychain Access utility as the name of the certificate. This is also the name you will use when referencing this certificate. Personally, I used the name, “My Signing Identity.”
4. Choose Code Signing from the Certificate Type menu.
5. Choose Self Signed Root from the Type popup menu.
6. Check the Let me override defaults checkbox.
7. Click Continue.
8. Specify a serial number for the certificate. Any number will do as long as you have no other certificate with the same name and serial number.
9. Click Continue.
10. Fill in the information for the certificate. You can use real or fake data, I used real data personally.
11. Click Continue.
12. Accept the defaults for the rest of the dialogs.

Once completed, you will see your certificate in Keychain Access. Verify the name you picked, and you’re done with this step. Well done!

**Step 2: (Re-)Sign your application**

Now you have to sign your application. To do this, open up Terminal again and use the following command:

```
codesign -s "My Signing Identity" -f $(which python)
```

A dialog will appear, click "Allow".

Now start your application again.  You will get the accept incoming connections dialog one last time.  Click "Allow".

[image]

From now on you should no longer get the warnings anymore! Now it is possible to enjoy the security of your firewall being active without the inconvenience of having to click "allow" constantly.

*Credit: The original source which served as a starting place for this updated and annotated solution guide was https://web.archive.org/web/20140228153242/http://silvanolte.com/blog/2011/01/18/do-you-want-the-application-to-accept-incoming-network-connections*

Comment: the credited link is gone now - I was hoping to find info as to whether self signing python leaves me vulnerable - any suggestions?

Comment: @memeLab Archive.org to the rescue! https://web.archive.org/web/20140228153242/http://silvanolte.com/blog/2011/01/18/do-you-want-the-application-to-accept-incoming-network-connections.  Answer updated.

Comment: Is there any way to batch-apply this to virtual envs?

Comment: Does this work on El Capitan (10.11)+? I tried, it succeeded, but still keeps asking to "allow incoming connections".

Comment: @DeveshKhandelwal: Did you find a way to figure it out? This solution worked for me on Mavericks, but not on El Capitan.

Comment: @David Unfortunately, no. I tried digging around a bit more, even signing the default Python framework that comes bundled but to no success. I think maybe it is because of SIP introduced in 10.11, and I'm on 10.12, so Apple is most probably going to tighten security. I haven't tried disabling that (it can only be disabled via recovery mode). :(

Comment: Doesn't work on 10.11+

Comment: For virtualenv user, make sure you activate the virtualenv, source into it, then run the cosign command. After accepting "allow" once, subsequent request will go through without the dialog.