# How to allow Python.app to firewall on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, certificate, firewall

When I run a python application on Mac, it shows many dialogs about want "Python.app" to accept incoming network connections.

Even I Allow it many times, it shows again and again.

How to allow it one time and not show any more?

[image]

---

## Edit

I found this question:
[Add Python to OS X Firewall Options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688841/add-python-to-os-x-firewall-options)

I followed the accepted answer to do but finally when I run `codesign -s "My Signing Identity" -f $(which python)`, it said:

```
/usr/bin/python: replacing existing signature
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate: can't create output file: /usr/bin/python.cstemp (Operation not permitted)
/usr/bin/python: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
```

How to do next?

Comment: (Operation not permitted) means that you are not allowed to perform an operation - in specific you cannot create a file in /usr/bin, which is in fact owned by root. Since you already disabled SIP, you should run `codesign` with `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently El Capitan has something call [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) that prevents any user (even root) to modify certain OS resources. Such as the /usr/bin directory in this case, where you have the python executable. To self sign the python binary you can disable SIP by rebooting your mac in recovery mode (reboot while holding CMD+R) and then typing this in the terminal:

`csrutil disable`

then boot back into regular OSX, and follow the steps to self sign python and execute:

`codesign -s "My Signing Identity" -f $(which python)`

and finally reboot back into Recovery Mode, and re-enable SIP:

`csrutil enable`

Comment: Thank you. If it can work in this way, I will say how terrible! It looks like hack. Indeed, I don't know why the software(like python library) don't match system environment any case friendly. It's not good for normal developers.

Comment: What happens is you're carrying over a version from python that you had previous to El Capitan. Another thing you can do is to simply re-install python user brew. 
Check this out: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/how-to-use-pip-after-the-el-capitan-max-os-x-upgrade
And this: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md

Comment: I have tried to reboot into recovery mode. But that need administrator password. I can login because of the company's computer.

Answer (score 6):

```
With the OS X firewall enabled, you can remove the "Do you want the application "python" to accept incoming network connections?" message.

Create a self-signed certificate.

Open Keychain Access. Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access.
Keychain Access menu > Certificate Assistant > Create a Certificate...
Enter a Name like "My Certificate".
Select Identity Type: Self Signed Root
Select Certificate Type: Code Signing
Check the Let me override defaults box
Click Continue
Enter a unique Serial Number
Enter 7300 for Validity Period.
Click Continue
Click Continue for the rest of the dialogs
Now sign your application

  codesign -s "My Certificate" -f $(which python)

In the dialog that appears, click "Allow".

Note that when using a virtual environment, you need to activate the virtual environment before running this command.
```

Comment: this answer works. no need to disable SIP. One side node is `codesign -s "My Certificate" -f $(which python)` doesn't work very well on my side. The workaround is to double click the certificate in keychains app, expand the Trust section, choose Always Trust under `Code Signing`

Answer (score 5):

I installed Python 3.6 from python.org, and I had a similar problem. I tried repeatedly to self-sign the python binaries /usr/local/bin/python3, /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3, and so forth, but I would keep getting the MacOS Firewall Deny/Allow popup.

Finally, self-signing the application located at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources did the trick:

```
codesign --force --sign "My Signing Identity" /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app
```

I'm on MacOS Mojave 10.14.1 for what that's worth.

Comment: if you were here, I might just kiss you. well, maybe not.

Comment: @mr-howdy, I gets error: `error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain` - can you help?

Comment: @Taz you can follow @Prasad 's answer below. Create a keychain certificate. After that you can also double click the certificate you created, expand Trust, in the `Code Signing` option choose Always Trust

Comment: This guy right here Mr. president, give him a medal

Answer (score 4):

Slight addendum to the answer by @mr-howdy above. For Python 3.7, I had to use:

```
codesign --force --sign "My Certificate" /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Note the extra `Contents/MacOS/Python` added to the path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Create a self-signed certificate.

- Open Keychain Access. Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access.
- Keychain Access menu > Certificate Assistant > Create a Certificate...
- Enter a Name like "My Certificate".
- Select Identity Type: Self Signed Root
- Select Certificate Type: Code Signing
- Check the Let me override defaults box
- Click Continue
- Enter a unique Serial Number (from 1 to 2147483647)
- Enter 7300 for Validity Period.
- Click Continue
- Click Continue for the rest of the dialogs
- Now sign your application, either by:

  - in terminal run `codesign -s --deep "My Certificate" -f $(which python)`
  - In the dialog that appears, click "Allow".

  or

  - open Keychains app, search for your certificate,
  - right-click to 'Get Info'
  - expand the Trust section, choose 'Always Trust' under Code Signing
    [image]

**Note** that when using a virtual environment, you need to activate the virtual environment before running this command.

Comment: This is a good answer because it goes through the steps of creating a code signing certificate. However, instead of using `$(which python)`, I used a path as my python3 was aliased.

Comment: In my case "--deep" wasn't recognized, but besides that it's a great answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can allow incoming connections for python in System Preferences->Security & Privacy. Click on the Firewall tab and then the Firewall Options button (you may need to authenticate/unlock first). You should see python listed somewhere and you can select to allow incoming connections. This solved the problem for me at least.

Comment: This only works once. The security dialog the OP asked for still pops up

Comment: hmm. for me this prevented the dialog from popping up again. but maybe i didn't do anything to trigger it since? running osx 10.14.5.