# Mac App on El Capitan with Python Child Process

Tags: python, macos, sockets

I have been building an Mac app and part of its architecture is that it spins off a python child process to index some files in the background (there are simpler libraries to use for indexing for python). It launches the python by executing the python file directly. The parent Mac app and child python process then communicate with each other through sockets.

After upgrading my MacBook to El Capitan, I've been hit with the firewall issue described here: [How to allow Python.app to firewall on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760163/how-to-allow-python-app-to-firewall-on-mac-os-x/34985338#34985338).

When I packaged my application and deployed it locally for the first time on El Capitan, I got the same "Do you want the application 'Python.app' to accept incoming network connections" dialog. I followed the steps in that post to resolve the issue for myself. However, my eventual goal is to distribute my app to other users, in that case I wouldn't want them to go through disabling the System Integrity Protection like the post suggested to make my app work.

I know I could try to integrate the indexing functionality into the Mac app itself, but what are some other possible solutions to this problem? How would I allow the python process to communicate via sockets without the users, or myself, needing to go through a complicated code signing process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps instead of using sockets, you could have your Python process communicate with the parent process by reading from stdin and/or writing to stdout?  That would avoid any interactions with the firewall.

Comment: I had thought about this solution, but wasn't too sure what happens when the python child process throws exceptions and that sort of stuff, is there a clean way to communicate via stdin/stdout without worrying about exceptions. And how would I debug in this case without the ability to print unstructured stuff to stdout (since it will need to conform to some kind of protocol).

Comment: Exceptions will work the same as before (i.e. they don't propagate through file descriptors).  Debugging in the parent process works the same as before.  Debugging in the child process is a bit trickier since now its stdout output goes to the parent process rather than to your Terminal; but you could have an option for the parent process to print any text it receives from the child process, or an option for the child process to log debug info to a file which you could then monitor via tail -f  (or etc)