# Do I have to run dask.distributed or dask.multiprocessing as sudo on Mac OS X?

Tags: dask

I am new to using dask for distributed/parallel computing. I have great problem to get it work on my Mac, but it seems to work when I run as root. This seems not be the best way of running long running programs. I there any solution to this?
/Tomas

Comment: this depends on how you installed python. Have a look into virtual environments or anaconda.

Comment: I recommend putting up an example that causes the issue and a more detailed error message of what is happening.

Comment: Well, one problem is that there is no error. The processes just stop processing but seems not to return any result and so does the program. When I run it using sudo it works, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have found the solution. It is not that I need to run as root, but that I cannot run it using a conda environment. If all environments are disabled it runs as expected. However, why this is the case is not clear to me. I know that wxpython has issues running with environment on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You do not need to have root permissions to use dask.distributed.

Comment: I have to give the spawned processes the right to accept incoming connections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237431/mac-app-on-el-capitan-with-python-child-process

Comment: My guess is that this is due to a firewall application that you have set up on your machine.  A stock OS-X machine does not usually have this problem.  It's worth noting that dask.distributed runs on the network, and so depends that the hostnames and ports that you specify are visible to other worker machines.

Comment: It seems to be the similar problem when I run using dask.multiprocessing. Should that be the same reason? when using distributed I only sometimes get the request to give permissions but that has never happened for multiprocessing.