# Allow Python.app on El Capitan (OS X)

Tags: python, macos

[image]

I'm using a `python` executable in a **virtual environment**. I tried doing the whole `codesign` thing as described [here](http://wpguru.co.uk/2015/06/how-to-kill-the-accept-incoming-connections-dialogue-on-your-mac-forever/), including creating the certificate, etc.  The command worked, but the result stayed the same.  I think it used to work on previous versions of OS X, but I currently use the most recent El Capitan version (10.11.6) and it's not working anymore.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

**EDIT**: I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760163/how-to-allow-python-app-to-firewall-on-mac-os-x) solution, but since my python is in a virtual environment, I'm not sure it applies, unless you guys say otherwise...

**EDIT 2**: I tried the solution above, didn't work. **I should mention that I am codesigning the python executable in the virtualenv**.

**EDIT 3**: The thing that ended up working for me was upgrading `flask` to the current version, (using `pip install flask --upgarde`), and running the app with `export FLASK_APP=app.py; flask run` instead of with `python app.py`.  When you run the app with `flask run`, the annoying dialog box doesn't pop up anymore.  No codesigning needed to my knowledge.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This isn't really a python specific question. My IDE will pop up with the same message when I run a server application

Comment: @cricket_007: but it's not IDE-specific. I get the same message if I run the app from the terminal.

Comment: And I don't think your virtualenv is contained as a part of the Python.app Bundle, so you'd have to add the python binary from the virtualenv directory

Comment: I didn't mean it's IDE specific either. I get it anywhere there's a port that needs opened, essentially

Comment: @cricket_007: I did add the python binary from the virtualenv directory... Perhaps I need to add the original python Bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is that happening?**

So the `python` executables in El Capitan spawns `.../Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app` + some extra magic. The problem is that the framework bundle doesn't have its own signature, and it uses signatures of parent application binaries.

**How to check?**

The first thing to check after installing applications from non-Apple-maintained-source-that-might-steal-your-soul, is to check if the application you are installing is *restricted*:

```
ls -lO /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
csrutil status
```

If it is **restricted** it cannot be removed (even with root) as long as [SIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html) is enabled.

**What to do?**

So you have several different options you must try:

- Pre-Option 0 - **I think you are doing it already**: I am not sure how you are maintaining your virtual environments, so just confirm you are going through the process, like [here](https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/).
- Option 1 - **safe, but might not work**: Use [`brew`](http://brew.sh/) to maintain your executables and [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to maintain your packages. That usually solves the problem immediately, but I am not sure what is your case :)
- Option 2 - **dangerous, but will work**: [Check](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html) and [Disable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) the SIP. Unless you work in an environment protected by a team of IT guys with years of security experience, I don't suggest it. This option WILL solve the issue, but you basically getting rid of one of the security layers... GL!

**UPDATE 1**

There is another option (not sure if you tried it though)

- Option 1.5 - **I have no idea if it will work**: Try *Option 1* (`csrutil disable`), reboot, go through the `codesign` process, reboot, and undo the *Option 1* (`csrutil enable`). I have never tried it, but it doesn't mean you can't :))) [Credit goes to this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760163/how-to-allow-python-app-to-firewall-on-mac-os-x?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I just checked, my python framework is *not* restricted (whew).  You're right about pre-option-0.  And I've tried your "UPDATE 1" (as described in my EDIT 2)... I do also have a python version installed view brew.  I tried to replace my executable with the brew executable, codesign both of them, and still no go...

Comment: If you are using `brew`, make sure you are using the `/usr/local/...` executables. In your scripts make sure the shebang is set to `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Maybe (just maybe) you are signing one binary, but using a different one?

Comment: I copied the executable from the `/usr/local/bin...` and my shebang points to the executable in my virtual environment `#!/Users/<blah>/Envs/<env>/bin/python`. I've made sure to codesign both the virtual environment executable as well as the original executable in the `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`

Comment: Thanks @RafazZ.  It's such an annoying problem

Comment: I am trying to replicate the problem, and got confused by your previous comment - Why are you copying the executables? Also, please confirm that the "Firewall Options..." is set to "Automatically allow signed software..."

Comment: can confirm the firewall options set to auto allow signed software... I'm using virtual environments, so I think in the creation of the virtual environment the wrapper function copies the `/Library/Frameworks/Python...` executable to the env directory.  In general I don't actually copy the exec myself, I let virtualenv handle everything.

Comment: are you able to replicate the problem?

Comment: No, I am not. I have created the virtual environment, signed using `$ codesign -f -s "NoNaMe" venv/bin/python`, and everything seems to be fine :(

Comment: Found a workaround.  It turns out that if I upgrade `flask` to the current version and run the app with `flask run` instead of with `python app.py`, I don't get the annoying dialog box.  I'm going to mark your answer as correct given the amount of effort you went into to help me.  Thanks again.