# How to open/enable port in Mac OSX, port 2377 for docker swarm

Tags: docker, macos-catalina

I am struggling with opening a port, 2377 for docker swarm connectivity.

Mac OSX specification:

```
System Version: macOS 10.15.2 (19C57)
Kernel Version: Darwin 19.2.0
```

There are lot of ways that I tried to open the port:

1. Enabled the firewall using System Preferences->Security and Privacy-> Firewall. Then edited `/etc/pf.conf` file as below, which doesn't help at all:

   ```
   pass in proto tcp from any to any port 2377
   pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8080
   ```
2. After enabling and disabling the firewall, the port 8080 which was enabled earlier got disabled and can not find any way to re-enable it again.
3. `ufw` is deprecated, and doesn't seems to work anymore.
4. `nc -l 8080` (netcat is of no use at all, never worked).
5. PFCTL (not working):

   ```
   HQTML git:(AD-14024)$ sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
   pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
   present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
   See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

   No ALTQ support in kernel
   ALTQ related functions disabled
   ```

Installed `nmap`, which shows:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-01-14 00:50 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00017s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 971 closed ports, 27 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
53/tcp   open  domain
8021/tcp open  ftp-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.43 seconds.
```

None of the previous posts seems to work anymore. Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Let me try that. Even if it doesn't work, we will solve this in further steps.
On the contrary, try allowing all traffic within the internal subnet.

Do a

```
docker network ls
```

and see the list of networks docker is using and the one we care about specifically in this problem is the ingress network.

```
docker network ingress inspect
```

I hope i could point you the rough direction to solve that issue. Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

I think, I have solved same problem. I need to open incoming requests to Python.

Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61462541/3270632

You should

1. create self-signed root certificate
2. codesign -s --deep "My Certificate" -f $(which python)
3. open Keychains app and select choose 'Always Trust' in "My Certificate" properties.

Now I can access to Django application running in virtualenv from another PC on LAN.

p.s. nmap shows closed, but it works
sudo nmap -sU -p 10000 -4 192.168.10.43
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
10000/udp closed ndmp