# Defer network access until user allowed it

Tags: macos, cocoa, network-programming, firewall, code-signing

When my Mac OS application starts the first time I am getting a popup "Do you want the application ... to accept incoming network connections?". How can I get some application code executed when the user has clicked on "Deny" or "Allow"? How can I determine if the application is allowed to accept incoming network connections?

Currently my application starts sending UDP broadcast packets to discover other devices on the network before it is able to receive responses. I am using the NSApplicationDelegate method applicationDidFinishLaunching to trigger using the network. Obviously that's to early for the first application start when the firewall popup appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not the sandbox but the firewall. sign your app and it won't ask this question

[Do you want the application to accept incoming network connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17527700/317461)

Alternatively add the proper stuff in xcode project settings to sign your app automatically when building:

[Xcode code signing guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Actually I had Xcode configured to use "Ad Hoc" signing certificate. The result was, getting the firewall popup each time I modified something in the app, but only the first time that version is started.

Comment: With my Mac developer certificate the popup does not appear anymore.

Comment: Initially the popup still appeared for one time with my Mac developer certificate. After subsequent modifications the popup did not appear. I am not 100% sure what I did wrong. Probably I used an old expired certificate.

Comment: The Xcode code signing guide says about the initial policy of the firewall: "Allow if a trusted anchor check succeeds; otherwise prompt the user."